# This funtion doesn't return the correct bool

Tags: c, methods, palindrome

I have made this function to check if my string is palindrome. When it is, it prints it, but when the string isn't palindrome, it doesn't print anything

```
bool is_palindrome(char cad[]){
  bool is = false;
  int size, i;

  size = 0;
  i = 0;
  while(cad[i] != '\0'){
    i++;
    size++;
  }

  i = 0;
  while(cad[i] != '\0'){
    if(cad[i] == cad[size - 1]){
      i++;
      size--;
      is = true;
    }else{
      is = false;
    }
  }


  if(is == true){
    printf("IS PALINDROME\n");
  }else if(is == false){
    printf("IT ISN'T PALINDROME");
  }

  return is;
}
```

my main is:

```
int main(){

  bool is 
  
  is = is_palindrome("ABCDCBA"); //It funtions well
  is = is_palindrome("Hello"); //It doesn't funtion

  return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example. This lacks the main. Keep in mind arrays decay to pointers to first element, you need to pass the size of array to function.

Comment: Why don't you step through it in a debugger and/or add debug print statements to trace the program execution? That is debugging 101 and should lead you closer to the root cause if not outright finding it. [How to debug small programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/)

Comment: I have just added my main @TonyTannous

Comment: `bool` is a keyword of C++, not C.

Comment: you can add `#include <stdbool.h>` in order to use `bool` isn't it @RohanBari?

Comment: @sonlas10 yes you can.

Comment: The program has nothing defined such include statement. That's why.

Answer (score 3):

You have an infinite loop. In the second while(), if the word is not a palindrome, it enters the `else` condition and you don't increment `i`. So the loop never exits!

You can simply `break` out from the loop here once you find one mismatched letter, since you know that the word is not a palindrome. Like this:

```
bool is_palindrome(char cad[]){
  bool is = false;
  int size, i;

  size = 0;
  i = 0;
  while(cad[i] != '\0'){
    i++;
    size++;
  }

  i = 0;
  while(cad[i] != '\0'){
    if(cad[i] == cad[size - 1]){
      i++;
      size--;
      is = true;
    }else{
      is = false;
      break;
    }
  }    

  if(is == true){
    printf("IS PALINDROME\n");
  }else if(is == false){
    printf("IT ISN'T PALINDROME");
  }

  return is;
}
```

You could even simplify it a bit further, such as:

```
  is = true;
  while(cad[i] != '\0') {
    if(cad[i] != cad[size - 1]){
      is = false;
      break;
    }
    i++;
    size--;
  }
```

Comment: Well that is actually what I am trying to say  I guess I will removed my answer

Comment: I don't understand why `i++` in the first `while` loop? It's already resetting to 0 in the next statement, why not directly `i++` in the loop...

Comment: @RohanBari Because if you don't increment `i`,  `cad[i] != '\0'` will never be false and the while will never exit.

Comment: @th33lf what if we could do `while (cad[size++] != '\0')`?